# Selected file name is not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have custom CSS for an input type file. This works fine but whenever I am selecting any file its name is not getting displayed, any suggestions or any help please?

```css
.fileContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.fileContainer [type=file] {
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
  font-size: 999px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  top: 0;
}


/* Example stylistic flourishes */

.fileContainer {
  background: #049fd9;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: .5em;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.fileContainer [type=file] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label class="fileContainer">
  Choose file
  <input type="file"/>
</label>
```

Comment: Added all my code and css too, also there is demo link for fiddle

Comment: Thanks. I added an answer for you

Comment: @Sudarshan Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function() {
$(".fileContainer").text($('input[type=file]').val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''))
})
```

Demo:

```js
$("input[type=file]").change(function() {
$(".fileContainer").text($('input[type=file]').val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''))

})
```

```css
.fileContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    
}

.fileContainer [type=file] {
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
    font-size: 999px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
}

/* Example stylistic flourishes */

.fileContainer {
  
    background: #049fd9;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: .5em;
    
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
   height:30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 200px;
}

.fileContainer [type=file] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="fileContainer">
    Choose file
    <input type="file"/>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you'll first need to add an element to the DOM to store the file names. Then you can loop through the `files` collection of the input and append the file names to that element. Try this:

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    html += '<p>' + this.files[i].name + '</p>';
  }
  $('#filelist').html(html);
});
```

```css
.fileContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.fileContainer [type=file] {
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
  font-size: 999px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  top: 0;
}

.fileContainer {
  background: #049fd9;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: .5em;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.fileContainer [type=file] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="fileContainer">
  Choose file
  <input type="file"/>
</label>

<div id="filelist"></div>
```

Comment: Yes rorry thanks, but I have accepted first ans as it was the one I was looking for, but I have given you one upvote cheers, amazing I will use this techniques also in my future projects.

Comment: No problem. Just be aware that you cannot change the file once you've selected it with the other logic. My answer lets you change the selected file multiple times if needed